# How to find all the source lines containing desired table names from user_source by using 'regexp'

Tags: regex, database, oracle

For example we have a large database contains lots of oracle packages, and now we want to see where a specific table resists in the source code. The source code is stored in user_source table and our desired table is called 'company'.

Normally, I would like to use:

```
select * from user_source 
where upper(text) like '%COMPANY%'
```

This will return all words containing 'company', like

```
121    company cmy
14     company_id, idx_name %% end of coding
453    ;companyname
1253   from db.company.company_id where 
989    using company, idx, db_name,
```

So how to make this result more intelligent using regular expression to parse all the source lines matching a meaningful table name (means a `table` to the compiler)?

So normally we allow the matched word contains chars like `.` `;` `,` `''` `""` but not `_`

Can anyone make this work?

Comment: Does `like` support full regex inside the string ?

Comment: @HippoMatrix - I've updated my answer so it will ignore the punctuation; sorry I missed that initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find company as a "whole word" with a regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM user_source
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text, '(^|\s)company(\s|$)', 'i');
```

The third argument of `i` makes the `REGEXP_LIKE` search case-insensitive.

As far as ignoring the characters `.` `;` `,` `''` `""`, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to suck them out of the string before doing the comparison:

```
SELECT * FROM user_source
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '[.;,''"]'), '(^|\s)company(\s|$)', 'i');
```

---

**Addendum**: The following query will also help locate table references. It won't give the source line, but it's a start:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_dependencies
WHERE referenced_name = 'COMPANY'
  AND referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: thanks, I am afraid it is not my point. what I want is to find out the 'source code', normally a trigger, proc, etc that containing a meaningful 'table' not a table as a whole word. because result also can be db.company.company_name or company; ,etc...........and any other meaningful table....

Comment: I don't fully understand. Do you want to find out which code references a specific table? If so, the `user_dependencies` view might be a better place to look: `SELECT * FROM user_dependencies WHERE referenced_name = 'COMPANY' and referenced_type = 'TABLE'`.

Comment: big thanks I just get this account so no authority to vote up~~

Comment: No worries. Did the query in my comment do the job then? If so I'll move it from the comment into the answer.

Comment: the above comment is just done in my 1st step. and the 2nd step is to trace back the result table set to the code line. we have 500+ tables and 49 package/package bodies to query... And some more general tables may come up mostly in all packages. So a good reg pattern will work for this.

Comment: and in my 2nd step only 44 distinct tables need to be queried

Comment: Hi, news here: the solution "REGEXP_REPLACE(text, '[.;,''"]'), '(^|\s)company(\s|$)', 'i')" is unable to capture code text like 'my.company.company_id' or 'my.company, ' because the `replace` can only find ,/./;/'/company,/./;/' as a word, but what I want is to find a row that contains the company table name, no matter how it was called.

Comment: So there should be some tricks can add any_String+'[.;,''"]'+any_String surround `company`.

Comment: If you change the `REGEXP_LIKE` regex from `'(^|\s)company(\s|$)'` to `'(^|\.|\s)company(\s|\.|$)'` it will be OK with the dots.

Comment: Thanks! it works! but it seems harder to make things more intelligent? like it allows ./,/; with any order? I am doing with the user_source table, as you know, to process the codes. it is really fuzzy~~

Comment: You're right - it is hard because you'll find exception after exception. For example, a table name could be in quotes or it could have a comma after it, and who knows what else. For that reason I'd recommend seeing if `USER_DEPENDENCIES` will work better for you; there's a sample query a few comments up.

Comment: USER_DEPENDENCIES will not give me the exact code line and already take into usage for retrieve the corresponding table, e.g. company is found out from this; also I find: REGEXP_LIKE(text,'([^_a-z0-9])company([^_a-z0-9])','i') may be more intelligent, not sure...

Comment: That regex may be as close as you can get. You may also want to exclude the dollar sign ($) and the pound sign (#) because those are valid table-name characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the objects that refer to your table, you can get that information from the data dictionary:

```
select *
from all_dependencies
where referenced_owner = 'DB'
and referenced_name = 'COMPANY'
and referenced_type = 'TABLE';
```

You can't get the individual line numbers from that, but you can then either look at `user_source` or use a regexp on the specific source code, which woudl at least reduce false positives.

Comment: thanks, this is just already done for my 1st step. and the 2nd step is to trace back the result `table` set to the `code line`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user_source
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text,'([^_a-z0-9])company([^_a-z0-9])','i')
```

Thanks @Ed Gibbs, with a little trick this modified answer could be more intelligent.